# opening and closing a new notebook

Tags: plotting

This work perfectly

```
CreateDocument[{TextCell[
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 7}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}], 
"Output"]}]
```

but if I want to change say 7 for 10, and reevaluate, Mathematica open a new windows without closing the first one.

With

```
PopupWindow[Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 20], 
TextCell[Manipulate[
Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 7}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}], "Output"]]
```

I must first close the window before to continue.

Is there a possibility to ask to close automaticaly?

Comment: Depends what do you mean by automaticaly: `NotebookClose[nb]; nb = CreateDocument[ ...`

Comment: Sorry  I do not know how to accept an answer. I appreciate very much the help of the community. And if I do not answer to the question of others, it is because I am still learning how to work with mathematica. In what concerns this question I wonder If one can close the previous Windows simply in reevaluating a command.

Comment: Now I have seen